# suma de una columna con un trigger mysql

Tags: mysql

Necesito de su ayuda ya que no soy bueno en el tema de disparadores (TRIGGER)en crear un trigger lo que pasa que tengo dos tablas una que es "jugador" y la otra de "equipo" como estan en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la tabla de jugador tengo un proceso almacenado que hace una división en las "columnas de rebotes hasta falta" y lo que quiero que haga "el trigger" es que "sume" lo que van ingresando en la tabla de "jugador" de las "columnas de rebotes hasta falta" y que ese resultado lo muestre en la tabla de "equipo" pero que también me deje ingresar los datos "nombre_jugador" hasta "peso" de esa misma tabla espero que me pueda ayudarme

```
create trigger  llenar after insert on jugador 
for each row 
begin 
insert into equipo(IDE,nombre_equipo,categoría,DT,capitán,Total_Victorias,Total_Derrotas,(select sum(Rebotes) from jugador),(select sum(Tiro_Libre) from jugador),(select sum(Bloqueos) from jugador),(select sum(Faltas) from jugador));
```

Answer (score 1):

¿Por qué insertarías varias veces en la tabla equipo?

Lo ideal sería insertar los jugadores del equipo y solo actualizar sus estadísticas de acuerdo a cada juego.

Ejemplo 
Jugador 1 total victorias 1 -tabla equipo

Al insertar una victoria en la tabla jugador, el trigger sumaria la victoria a las existentes. o bien podrías generar la información con un JOIN.